# Export HTML Table to EXCEL File using php

Tags: export-to-excel

I would like to ask for code which output a html table into excel given that the html table is in result.php

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is a pure table (i.e. no graph), you should consider using the csv (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format instead of excel. I don't knwow your skills in programmation, but this should not be hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$test="<table border=1><tr><td>Cell 1</td><td>Cell 2</td></tr></table>";
header('Pragma: public');
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel"); 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfile.xls");
echo $test;
```

Comment: Although there is a problem. i am using ms excel 2007 . and there cells are not visible when i export file. it gives message before open that "the file you are trying to open has different format than specified by the extension". Edit is welcome and appreciated if some one can tell why is so

Answer (score -1):

```
function exporttoexcel(){
var i;
var j;
var mycell;
var tableID = "crtfdetails";

var objXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var objWB = objXL.Workbooks.Add();
var objWS = objWB.ActiveSheet;

for (i=0; i < document.getElementById(tableID).rows.length; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j < document.getElementById(tableID).rows(i).cells.length; j++)
    {
        mycell = document.getElementById(tableID).rows(i).cells(j)
        objWS.Cells(i+1,j+1).Value = mycell.innerText;
    }
}
objWS.Range("A1", "Z1").EntireColumn.AutoFit();
objXL.Visible = true;
}
```